# use std::fill to populate vector with increasing numbers

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to fill a `vector<int>` using `std::fill`, but instead of one value, the vector should contain numbers in increasing order after.

I tried achieving this by iterating the third parameter of the function by one, but this would only give me either vectors filled with 1 or 2 (depending of the position of the `++` operator).

Example:

```
vector<int> ivec;
int i = 0;
std::fill(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), i++); // elements are set to 1
std::fill(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), ++i); // elements are set to 2
```

Comment: Use `std::iota` instead of `std::fill` (assuming your compiler is new enough to support it, anyway).

Comment: Unfortuntely, this seems to be part of the new standard (which I mustn't use). I saw the BOOST library has such a function, but it doesn't accept vectors (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/new/iota.html) but some custom type.
Isn't there another option?

Comment: user1612880, if you can't use C++11/Boost, just use Liran's code. It's not a _requirement_ that every operation has to be on one single line nor is there a world-wide shortage of characters available to C source code files :-)

Comment: It wouldn't have been for shortage but for performance. However, if there is no way to make this possible without cruel hacks, I'll use the solution provided by Liran.

Comment: @user1612880 Have you tried it with `std::vector`.  The boost version is a function template, and the "type name" of the first argument specifies a concept.  It's hard to tell, because I can only find a very formalistic specification, and no simple description, but I think that `std::vector` conforms to the concept.

Comment: Yes, `boost::range::iota` works perfectly with a `std::vector`. Yes, `std::vector` models `ForwardRange` (`RandomAccessRange`, to be exact).

Answer (score 182):

Preferably use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
// ...
std::vector<int> v(100) ; // vector with 100 ints.
std::iota (std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0); // Fill with 0, 1, ..., 99.
```

That said, if you don't have any `c++11` support (still a real problem where I work), use [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
// ...
struct IncGenerator {
    int current_;
    IncGenerator (int start) : current_(start) {}
    int operator() () { return current_++; }
};

// ...

std::vector<int> v(100) ; // vector with 100 ints.
IncGenerator g (0);
std::generate( v.begin(), v.end(), g); // Fill with the result of calling g() repeatedly.
```

Comment: what on earth does `iota` stand for, anyway?  (Looks like someone mistyped the equally clear `itoa`.)

Comment: It doesn't "stand" for anything, it is the Greek equivalent of the letter i. It is the name used for a [similar function in APL](http://aplwiki.com/LearnApl/BuiltInFunctions#line-176), and array language that sparked many of the ideas in Stepanov's STL.

Comment: Ah-ha thanks! OK so it is a word rather than a initialism; I might have better luck remembering that now. CPP Reference talked about "Increments Of The starting value" (note the slight similarity) so I got initials in my head. (And the greek connection is not immediately obvious by Googling.) Thanks for the historical reference, too.

Answer (score 62):

You should use `std::iota` algorithm (defined in `<numeric>`):

```
  std::vector<int> ivec(100);
  std::iota(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), 0); // ivec will become: [0..99]
```

Because `std::fill` just assigns the given fixed value to the elements in the given range `[n1,n2)`. And `std::iota` fills the given range `[n1, n2)` with sequentially increasing values, starting with the initial value and then using `++value`.You can also use `std::generate` as an alternative.

Don't forget that `std::iota` is C++11 STL algorithm. But a lot of modern compilers support it e.g. GCC, Clang and VS2012 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj651033.aspx

P.S. This function is named after the integer function `⍳` from the programming language APL, and signifies a Greek letter iota. I speculate that originally in APL this odd name was chosen because it resembles an `“integer”` (even though in mathematics iota is widely used to denote the imaginary part of a complex number).

Comment: You might want to add std::iota is from C++11

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov But most places aren't using the latest version of the compiler, and can't use C++11.

Comment: `iota` was in the STL more than 15 years ago, so some compilers have always supported it, long before C++11

Comment: That vector will have a size 0. You would need to add a size to the container:
  std::vector<int> ivec( 100);
  std::iota(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), 0);

Answer (score 15):

My first choice (even in C++11) would be
`boost::counting_iterator` :

```
std::vector<int> ivec( boost::counting_iterator<int>( 0 ),
                       boost::counting_iterator<int>( n ) );
```

or if the vector was already constructed:

```
std::copy( boost::counting_iterator<int>( 0 ),
           boost::counting_iterator<int>( ivec.size() ),
           ivec.begin() );
```

If you can't use Boost: either `std::generate` (as suggested in
other answers), or implement `counting_iterator` yourself, if
you need it in various places.  (With Boost, you can use
a `transform_iterator` of a `counting_iterator` to create all
sorts of interesting sequences.  Without Boost, you can do a lot
of this by hand, either in the form of a generator object type
for `std::generate`, or as something you can plug into a hand
written counting iterator.)

Comment: In the first piece of code, which *constructor* of `std::vector` is being called? Has to be the *range constructor*, but is `boost::counting_iterator` implicitly convertible to an *InputIterator*?

Answer (score 11):

I've seen the answers with std::generate but you can also "improve" that by using static variables inside the lambda, instead of declaring a counter outside of the function or creating a generator class :

```
std::vector<int> vec(10);
std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [] {
    static int i = 0;
    return i++;
});
```

I find it a little more concise

Comment: `static` has the wrong semantics here, IMO. I would use a generalised capture `[i = 0]() mutable` so that it's clear that the variable is scoped to the specific instance of the lambda, not its generated class type. It's hard to contrive a situation where there would be a difference in practice, and that would probably indicate a questionable design, but in any case I think the semantics are superior using a member variable. Plus, it makes for more concise code; now the lambda's body can be a single statement.

Comment: Yeah that looks better ; I had never seen a variable initialized in the lambda capture before :)

Comment: This doesn't generate anything. `vec` is empty.  Though I was trying to find something in `std` that would generate a series of incrementing values into an empty container. :(

Answer (score 7):

We can use [generate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate/) function which exists in algorithm header file.

### Code Snippet :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    vector<int>v(10);

    int n=0;

    generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&n] { return n++;});

    for(auto item : v)
    {
      cout<<item<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant answer and is probably the most concise in the general case.

Comment: IMO it is superior to make `n` a member of the lambda via generalised capture `[n = 0]() mutable`, so it does not pollute the surrounding scope.

Comment: I'm using this one. May not be useful for advanced situations but good enough for c++ beginners. good solution if one can use lambda.

Answer (score 6):

std::iota is limited to a sequence n, n+1, n+2, ...

But what if you want to fill an array with a generic sequence f(0), f(1), f(2), etc.? Often, we can avoid a state tracking generator. For example,

```
int a[7];
auto f = [](int x) { return x*x; };
transform(a, a+7, a, [a, f](int &x) {return f(&x - a);});
```

will produce the sequence of squares

```
0 1 4 9 16 25 36
```

However, this trick will not work with other containers.

If you're stuck with C++98, you can do horrible things like:

```
int f(int &x) { int y = (int) (long) &x / sizeof(int); return y*y; }
```

and then

```
int a[7];
transform((int *) 0, ((int *) 0) + 7, a, f);
```

But I would not recommend it. :)

Comment: OP cannot use C++11 (no lambas)

Answer (score 5):

If you'd rather not use C++11 features, you can use [`std::generate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate/):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Generator {
    Generator() : m_value( 0 ) { }
    int operator()() { return m_value++; }
    int m_value;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> ivec( 10 );

    std::generate( ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), Generator() );

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it, end = ivec.end();
    for ( it = ivec.begin(); it != end; ++it ) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This program prints 0 to 9.

Comment: You can probably use a lambda: `[]() { return i++;}` (with a previously defined `int i = 0;`) instead of `Generator`.

Comment: @bitmask Surely if you have lambdas you have `std::iota` anyway, no?

Comment: @bitmask But that would require C++11 :)

Comment: @bitmask This would contradict the actual premise of the answer, no?

Comment: What is quite unintuitive and non-streamlined is the fact that `it` and `end` are defined outside of the for-loop. Any reason for this?

Comment: @ChristianRau: It's a way to avoid calling `std::vector<T>::end()` repeatedly without having to type the iterator type name `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` more than once, just a habit. In my real code I do the same, and it usually doesn't matter since the functions are so short that the scope of `it` and `end` is very small. Now, you could argue that calling `end()` is ridicuously cheap and that I should just type `for ( std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = ivec.begin(); it != ivec.end(); ++it )` but that line is so much longer. :-)

Comment: @ChristianRau: Now another sad real world case is that I often have to work with MSVC6, and MSVC6 doesn't get scoping of variables declared in `for` loops right. I.e. with MSVC6 `for (int x;;) {} for (int x;;) {}` doesn't compile.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe The second reason sounds reasonable (as far as such a stupid VS bug can be reasonable at all, though, it's changable in the project settings), but I don't get the first reason, what's wrong with `std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(), end = ivec.end()` (neither repeated typing nor repeated calling)? And the line being longer, well, it's C++ and you won't get around some occasional line break anyway (and the days of good old 80-character displays are over). But it's a matter of taste I guess and you got my upvote long ago, anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Oh, right - I forgot that alternative you mention. I actually used that for a while but eventually stopped doing so because I don't like assigning multiple variables in a single like, i.e. I tend to despise it in the same was as `int x = 3, y = 4`. The only annoyance I have with my current approach is that the scope of `it` and `end` is larger than it needs to be, but in practice it's not much of an issue because my functions are a lot smaller than they used to be - so the scope isn't *that* much bigger.

Comment: @ChristianRau: To be totally honest: in practice I use whatever style the code in the file I'm editing uses, i.e. I value consistency higher than and of the advantanges or disadvantages we mentioned so far.

Comment: It is *still* unintuitive & non-streamlined to declare outside `for`, when `for` has a declaration clause available that got ignored for some reason. Doing so avoids polluting the entire scope with generic names - which won't be needed anywhere else, might be needed for a different type, might lead to thinkos, etc. Thus, I would write it that way: `for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = ivec.begin(), end = ivec.end(); it != end; ++it )`. Add `auto` & line breaks to taste. The one annoyance here is that `end` can't be `const`, but that's not the end of the world, & neither was yours anyway!

Answer (score 4):

There is another option - without using iota.
For_each + lambda expression can be used:

```
vector<int> ivec(10); // the vector of size 10
int i = 0;            // incrementor
for_each(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), [&](int& item) { ++i; item += i;});
```

Two important things why it's working:

1. Lambda captures outer scope [&] which means that i will be available inside expression
2. item passed as a reference, therefore, it is mutable inside the vector

Answer (score 2):

this also works

```
j=0;
for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = myvector.begin() ; it != myvector.end(); ++it){
    *it = j++;
}
```

Comment: Of course manually poking around with iterators works, but if the OP wanted to do that, they wouldn't have asked about an stdlib algorithm, would they?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of boost:

```
auto ivec = boost::copy_range<std::vector<int>>(boost::irange(5, 10));
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance you should initialize the vector with use of `reserve()` combined with `push_back()` functions like in the example below:

```
const int numberOfElements = 10;

std::vector<int> data;
data.reserve(numberOfElements);

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
    data.push_back(i);
```

All the `std::fill`, `std::generate`, etc. are operating on range of existing vector content, and, therefore the vector must be filled with some data earlier. Even doing the following: `std::vector<int> data(10);` creates a vector with all elements set to its default value (i.e. 0 in case of `int`).

The above code avoids to initialize vector content before filling it with the data you really want. Performance of this solution is well visible on large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** want to use `std::fill` and are confined to C++98 you can use something like the following,

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct increasing {
    increasing(int start) : x(start) {}
    operator int () const { return x++; }
    mutable int x;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<int> v(10);
    fill(v.begin(), v.end(), increasing(0));
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question, but I am currently playing with [library](http://github.com/dawikur/htl) to handle exactly this problem. It requires c++14.

```
#include "htl.hpp"

htl::Token _;

std::vector<int> vec = _[0, _, 100];
// or
for (auto const e: _[0, _, 100]) { ... }

// supports also custom steps
// _[0, _%3, 100] == 0, 4, 7, 10, ...
```

Comment: Yikes. That is some very hard to read code, and it would also be invalid at global scope, as written, because identifiers beginning with `_` are reserve to the implementation there.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found would be to use `std::generate_n` with `std::back_insert_iterator`. This example is actually given in the [cppreference page for std::back_insert_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator). One change I would make to this example, however, would be to reserve the number of inserts you are about to make to minimize reallocations like so:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(10);
std::generate_n(std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(v), 10, [n=0]() mutable { return ++n; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ 23, [`ranges::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/iota) can be used.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(5); // initialize with 5 zeros
    std::ranges::iota(v, 0); // fill with consecutive integers starting from 0
    // v={0,1,2,3,4}
}
```

Alternatively, to add elements starting from an empty `vector`, [`ranges::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/generate_n) can be used (since C++ 20) in conjunction with [`back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream> // only used for output in this example
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(5); // allocate enough space for elements
    std::ranges::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 5, [i=0]() mutable {return i++;});
    // use ++i to start from 1 instead of 0
    std::ranges::copy(v, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); // 0 1 2 3 4 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple templated function, `Sequence()`, for generating sequences of numbers. The functionality follows the `seq()` function in R ([link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/seq)). The nice thing about this function is that it works for generating a variety of number sequences and types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> Sequence(T min, T max, T by) {
  size_t n_elements = ((max - min) / by) + 1;
  std::vector<T> vec(n_elements);
  min -= by;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    min += by;
    vec[i] = min;
  }
  return vec;
}
```

Example usage:

```
int main()
{
    auto vec = Sequence(0., 10., 0.5);
    for(auto &v : vec) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The only caveat is that all of the numbers should be of the same inferred type. In other words, for doubles or floats, include decimals for all of the inputs, as shown.

**Updated: June 14, 2018**

Answer (score 0):

brainsandwich and underscore_d gave very good ideas. Since to fill is to change content, for_each(), the simplest among the STL algorithms, should also fill the bill:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [i=0] (int& x) mutable {x = i++;});
```

The generalized capture `[i=o]` imparts the lambda expression with an invariant and initializes it to a known state (in this case 0). the keyword `mutable` allows this state to be updated each time lambda is called.

It takes only a slight modification to get a sequence of squares:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [i=0] (int& x) mutable {x = i*i; i++;});
```

To generate R-like seq is no more difficult, but note that in R, the numeric mode is actually double, so there really isn't a need to parametrize the type. Just use double.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function template `make_vec` that will return a `std::vector` with the elements in increasing order as shown below:

```
template<std::size_t N> std::vector<int> make_vec()
{
    std::vector<int> tempArray(N);
    int count = 0;
    for (auto& elem : tempArray)
    {
        elem = ++count;
    }
    
    return tempArray;
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = make_vec<10>(); //uses ELEMENT_COUNT by default
    for(const auto&elem: vec)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Working demo C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/bGPj5dTGz)

The output of the above program is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Note that with `c++20` you can even mark `make_vec` as `constexpr`. [Demo C++20](https://godbolt.org/z/nGezWo6zE).