# How to memset on 2d vector

Tags: c++, fill, memset, 2d-vector

So I have a 2D Vector here that I want to assign a value num, I want to see which performs better fill vs memset() as  C++ noob, I am actually having problem setting the proper code syntax as I just always get Segmentation fault when I do it.

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix(10, vector<int>(10000000));
int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    int i = 0;
    for (auto &i : matrix)
    {
        fill(i.begin(), i.end(), num); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: perfom better in terms of what? In terms of not confusing the reader of your code `memset` isnt that nice, because there is no obvious reason to use it ;)

Comment: Show us your memset attempt?

Comment: Not diretly related to your question, but the `int i = 0;` declaration is pointless, you can remove it alltogether.

Comment: You can't `memset` to arbitary `int`s.

Comment: memset works on bytes, if you use memset with with `1` you'll get ints of value 16843009, see [this example on ideone](https://ideone.com/VrdDov)

Comment: Thanks for the support guys, very new at this, for my memset attempt
memset(&matrix[0], num, sizeof(matrix[0]) * matrix.size());
I'm pretty sure I used it wrongly though.

Comment: @Zambodia -- Your usage of `memset` will not work as you think it will work, so forget about it.  Even if it were not `vector` and was a regular array, `memset` will not work as intended.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for pointing that out, I guess you already understood what I wanted to do and clearly stated that it might really be impossible.

Answer (score 5):

[You **can** use `memset` for `std::vector<int>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665018/memset-on-vector-c), I don't think it's be such a good idea and it's fairly ugly with `std::vector`. Yes you can use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) the way you using it but there is a simpler way in your case, use `std::vector` constructor. Like this :

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    std::cin >> num;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(10, std::vector<int>(10000000, num));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In case that the right most dimension is **always** fixed, one can have all those items as a [ContiguousContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept) concept like `vector<array<int,10000000>> vv{10, array<int,10000000>{num} };`

Comment: Thanks Hamed for the reply, but I'd like to use the case where I need to assign a value(possibly different from each other) for the time being though I have only used a substitute that I assign 1 value to all.

Comment: @Zambodia I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but if you need to fill `std::vector` with different numbers you need to do it step-by-step, like using `push_back` and if there is a sequence that you want to fill your vector with it, I think this is the way to go -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694579/use-stdfill-to-populate-vector-with-increasing-numbers

Comment: @Hamed, Thanks I will probably use this then.