# Manipulating vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I am trying to create an array of object type teaStep, aswell as attempting to reorder a list to a random list.

The function `makeSteps` is meant to initiate the variables and store them in an array and output them.
The function `randomizeSteps` is meant to make an array of ints and randomize their order, before outputting the new array.
Just wondering if this is the right way to do it.
[edited]
 Using a vector, I now have this:

```
  auto makeSteps()
{
    auto all_steps = std::vector<teaStep>{};
    all_steps.emplace_back("Pick your tea", 1);
    all_steps.emplace_back("Boil water", 2);
    all_steps.emplace_back("Get tea bag in mug or pot", 3);
    all_steps.emplace_back("Pour boiled water over teabag", 4);
    all_steps.emplace_back("Wait!", 5);
    all_steps.emplace_back("Remove teabag", 6);
    all_steps.emplace_back("Add milk and/ or sugar", 7);
    all_steps.emplace_back("Mix, drink and enjoy", 8);


    return all_steps;
}

   auto randomizeSteps()
{
    vector <int> ranstep;
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
        ranstep.push_back(i);
    auto rng = std::default_random_engine{};
    std::shuffle(std::begin(ranstep), std::end(ranstep), rng);
    return ranstep;
}
```

To add to this, once this is complete, I must be able to utilise the objects in the vectors, however when I try this I get an error, example below:

```
//should go through the object in vectors, and compare the field Order, to int a.
teaStep findStep(int a, std::vector<teaStep> vectors)

{
    for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++)
    {
        teaStep test = vectors[b];
        if (test.getOrder == a)
            return test;
    }
}
```

The error I get is "no conversion from int to int(..."

Comment: `makeSteps` returns a dangling pointer, which points to a local array that fell out of scope

Comment: There is a good list of books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: this question has changed a lot since two edits and not sure what the problem is anymore.

Comment: I have edited the post to more clearly state my question

Comment: Please don't update the question as you solve your problems - it makes existing answers incomprehensible. Accept an answer and post a new question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return a pointer to a local variable here:

```
    teaStep arr[] = /* ... */;
    return arr;
}
```

The lifetime of `arr` ends as soon as you exit `makeSteps` (at the closing `}`). And whenever you manipulate the return value of `makeSteps`, you get garbage.

Try and use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of plain C arrays, for instance:

```
auto make_steps()
{
    auto steps = std::vector<teaStep>{};
    steps.emplace_back("Pick your tea", 1);
    steps.emplace_back("Boil water", 2);
    steps.emplace_back("Get tea bag in mug or pot", 3);
    steps.emplace_back("Pour boiled water over teabag", 4);
    steps.emplace_back("Wait!", 5);
    steps.emplace_back("Remove teabag", 6);
    steps.emplace_back("Add milk and/ or sugar", 7);
    steps.emplace_back("Mix, drink and enjoy", 8);
    return steps;
}
```

Comment: I don't get the emplace_back, with the code I showed above, I initiated all 8 teaSteps first, using vector, I now have this:

Comment: `emplace_back` constructs a `teaStep` in the vector, rather than copying an existing `teaStep`. You don't need to give names (`step1`, ... `step8`) to those `teaSteps`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @YSC said, please don't use `std:random_shuffle`. It is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600100/why-are-stdshuffle-methods-being-deprecated-in-c14).

Use `std::shuffle` instead.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

auto makeSteps()
{
    auto steps = std::vector<teaStep>{};
    steps.emplace_back("Pick your tea", 1);
    steps.emplace_back("Boil water", 2);
    steps.emplace_back("Get tea bag in mug or pot", 3);
    steps.emplace_back("Pour boiled water over teabag", 4);
    steps.emplace_back("Wait!", 5);
    steps.emplace_back("Remove teabag", 6);
    steps.emplace_back("Add milk and/ or sugar", 7);
    steps.emplace_back("Mix, drink and enjoy", 8);
    return steps;
}


auto randomizeSteps()
{
    std::vector<int> ranstep(10) ; // vector with 10 ints.
    std::iota (std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0); // Fill with 0, 1, ..., 9.
    auto rng = std::default_random_engine{};
    std::shuffle(std::begin(ranstep), std::end(ranstep), rng);
    return ranstep;
}
```

Comment: Please check my edited question, I presume this is correct?I shall try to now use the vectors in the rest of my code, thank you.

Comment: I would prefer `std:iota` for `randomizeSteps`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694579/use-stdfill-to-populate-vector-with-increasing-numbers

Comment: For the next time, please ask two separated questions.